# Return value invalid for DirectorySearch in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directorysearcher

I'm having an issue looking up user information in AD with the System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher object.  The first time I run the command instead of returning a result, it returns the string value "System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult".  I have run .GetType() on the variable holding this result, and it comes back as String.

The second time, and all subsequent times, that I run this script, it returns the user object I'm looking for.  Here's my code.

```
$MyDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$ADSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher

$ADSearcher.SearchRoot = $MyDomain
$ADSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$ADSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$ADSearcher.Filter = "samaccountname=myaccount"
$User = $ADSearcher.FindOne()
```

I'm running Powershell 3 on 2008 R2.

Update: I don't think I was clear about the circumstances in which it works.  If I run the script once, and search for 5 different users using FindOne(), they all come back incorrectly.  If I run the program again immediatly, it then retrieves the user objects for all 5.  This suggests that it's something in the environment, but I sure can't figure out what it is. I am running the script from within the ISE.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just use the Active Directory SnapIn and use Get-ADUser?

Comment: Yes, this is in a logon script and the users are very sensitive to logon times.  Using Get-ADUser would add about 4 seconds.  I know it's not much but these are the conditions we've been given.

Comment: I finally figured out what was going on.  I did not realize that the $User variable had previously been used in the script to hold the user's logon ID - a string.  Instead of re-using the $User variable, I renamed the variable to hold the return value to $ADUser, and it works great now.